# qTranslate ignores language in url

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I want to create a website written in two languages. I used qTranslate and it seems to be working okay. But, I have couple of conditional elements in my theme, like:

```
<li><a href="/<?php if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='en') { ?>en<?php } else { ?>pl<?php } ?>></li>
```

Which detects if either language is `pl` or `en` and creates the link according to that. But, when I click the link `http://localhost/en/something` for example, it ommits `en` and loads `http://localhost/something` with default language. What can I do to change it?

edit: this happens only on custom post types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. Adding `/` at the end of the link helped.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this problem too. Adding `/` didn't make any difference.

Using `?setlang=no` instead solved my problem.

Source: [qTranslate-X FAQ](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq/#CustomMenuConvertURL)